# Difference in two simpledateformat dates in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, simpledateformat

I am attempting to calculate difference in an entry/exit time by doing something like this:

`SELECT entry_time - exit_time AS dwell`

However, believe the values are in SimpleDateFormat:

```
2017-07-15T13:00:37-05:00
```

and as a result, I have had trouble figuring out what to CAST or CONVERT them to in Postgre Sql

I was able to do this in PySpark, but now I need to do this just using standard SQL. Here is an example of what worked in Spark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
timeDiff = (F.unix_timestamp('exit_time', format=timeFmt)
        - F.unix_timestamp('entry_time', format=timeFmt))
new_sdf = sdf.withColumn("Dwell", timeDiff)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast such a value to get a timestamp in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT CAST('2017-07-15T13:00:37-05:00' AS timestamp with time zone);

      timestamptz
------------------------
 2017-07-15 20:00:37+02
(1 row)
```

Then use timestamp arithmetic and subtract the two timestamps to get an `interval`.